# Shopware 6 Command './psh.phar administration:build.' is not working

Tags: shopware

I am using Shopware 6. I am creating the module which dispaly component ( Grid ) in back-end.

When building the administration via the command `./psh.phar administration:build` it said that no such file directory so can anyone help me to move forward ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you use the development-template from github?
https://github.com/shopware/development

When using the installer, you won't be able to build the administration, you need to use the development template to create plugins, not the installer.

Comment: download the zip file from their now vendor folder is not their ( git clone git@github.com:shopware/platform.git )  is give permission denided

Comment: I don't get your comment. You need to set up the installation as described here: https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-platform-dev-en/getting-started/installation-guide

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the **production** template, just run `bin/build-administration.sh` instead